# Routes causing undefined behaviour in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a React application with routing and have it set up currently as

```
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={TourneyOverview}> 
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/game/:gameIndex' component={GameScore}> </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
```

if I go to '/game/:gameIndex' the GameScore component properly loads but when I go to '/' I get an undefined error in the GameScore component. I'm not sure what's causing the error, is there anything I need to do to make sure that the component is ready even if it is not included in the current route.

Edit:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    games: state.games
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(changeGameScore, dispatch);
}

const GameScore = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Game);

export default GameScore;

const Game = ({games}) => {
  return (
    <div className="GameContainer">
      <div className="TeamContainer">
        {games.round1[0].team1Name}
        <div>
          {games.round1[0].team1Score}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="TeamContainer">
        {games.round1[0].team2Name}
        <div>
          {games.round1[0].team2Score}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

The games reducer:

```
function games(state = [], action) {
  return state;
}

export default games;
```

Root reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({teams,
  games});


export default rootReducer;
```

[image]

Comment: Please add error stacks details here, please add GameScore component code as well

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" has a very specific meaning and this is not it. If you get an error message saying something is undefined it's not "undefined behaviour".

Comment: yeah that was my bad, I should have said that it was undefined

Comment: No images of code, please. Post the code as text.

Comment: I would suspect that your function is called with `games` being null after reading the error message. Can you show code for your games reducer?

Comment: added the games reducer and the root reducer, there isn't much there because I want to make sure everything works together